# Android how ping test Work?

Tags: java, android

I want to know how ping test work in android?
Code I find is given below

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = runtime.exec("ping -c 1 " + host);
proc.waitFor();     
int exit = proc.exitValue();
```

from where i get information about the string that we provide to runtime.exec() methode;

Comment: InetAdress.isReachable should do the job, no?

Answer (score 0):

Use: [Jpingy](https://code.google.com/p/jpingy/) library. Example:

```
PingArguments arguments = new PingArguments.Builder().url("google.com").timeout(5000).repeat(2).bytes(32).build();
PingResults results = Ping.ping(arguments,Backend.UNIX);
```